# Safari doesn't interpret url variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I am using the Oauth implicit grant flow for logging into an application. When a user accesses the site who is not authenticated, they are sent to a url with the following structure:

```
baseurl + '/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=' + redirecturl
```

`baseurl` is the location of the page which contains the inputs for entering your username and password. When you enter correct credentials and click the 'sign in' button on that page you should be directed to the `redirecturl`. `redirecturl` is the location of the application itself (an angular app), that the user first tried to access.

The following code handles the particular case occurring after the user has logged in:

```
$urlRouterProvider
            .when('/token_type=bearer&access_token=:accessToken', function ($location, $state, User, storageService) {
                    storageService.clearAll();
                    User.authenticate($location.path().substr(1));
                    $state.go('marketplace.applications');
                }
        );
```

When I use Chrome, everything works as expected. When I use Safari, the code above is never executed.

Notice the `:accessToken` included in the string passed to `$urlRouterProvider.when()`.

I did some investigating and found that I can reproduce the same behavior in Chrome if I remove the `:accessToken` part of the string passed to `$urlRouterProvider.when()`. This leads me to believe that Safari doesn't know how to interpret the `:accessToken` variable. Is there something about how Safari interprets urls that is not compatible with the code I have in place or is it something else entirely?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the `:accessToken` was a red herring.

The reason removing `:accessToken` caused the same behavior in Chrome was because it meant that url wasn't matching what was in the browser, so the code wasn't executing. However, in Safari the code was not executing due to a *different* mismatch in the url, having to do with what the `redirecturl` was set to.

Originally I had set the `redirecturl` to `baseurl + '/test'`. This caused the url kicked back from the server to be `baseurl + 'test/#token_type'`.

When navigating to this url, Chrome automatically added a `/`, changing the url to `baseurl + 'test/#/token_type'`, which my `$urlRouterProvider.when()` function was able to match.

Safari did not add a `/` so `$urlRouterProvider.when()` never found a match and the code didn't execute.

**I was able to solve this by setting my initial `redirecturl` to `baseurl + '/test/'` instead of `baseurl + '/test'`**